# Twitter - Hadoop Data Streaming

Tags: hadoop

How do we get the twitter(Tweets) into HDFS for offline analysis. we have a requirement to analyze tweets.

Answer (score 3):

I would look for solution in well developed area of streaming logs into hadoop, since the task looks somewhat similar. 
There are two existing systems doing so: 
Flume: https://github.com/cloudera/flume/wiki 
And
Scribe: https://github.com/facebook/scribe

So your task will be only to pull data from twitter, what I asume is not part of this question and feed one of these systems with this logs.

Answer (score 1):

[Fluentd](http://fluentd.org/) log collector just released its WebHDFS plugin, which allows the users to instantly stream data into HDFS.

[image]

- [Fluentd + Hadoop: Instant Big Data Collection](http://blog.treasure-data.com/post/35644151211/fluentd-hadoop-instant-big-data-collection)

Also by using [fluent-plugin-twitter](https://github.com/y-ken/fluent-plugin-twitter), you can collect Twitter streams by calling its APIs. Of course you can create your custom collector, which posts streams to Fluentd. Here's a Ruby example to post logs against Fluentd.

- [Fluentd: Data Import from Ruby Applications](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/ruby)

Answer (score 0):

This can be a solution to your problem.

- Tools to capture Twitter tweets

  - [Create PDF, DOC, XML and other docs from Twitter tweets](http://twdocs.com/)
  - [Tweets to CSV files](http://lifehacker.com/5040650/tweetake-backs-up-your-tweets-to-csv-files)
- Capture it in any format. (csv,txt,doc,pdf.....etc)
- Put it into HDFS.